# Solving a $3\times3$ non-linear system

Tags: trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, diagonalization, nonlinear-system

### Problem Formulation

Let $M\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a covariance matrix given by the following factorization
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}M &=(RE)(RE)'\\
&=R\,EE'\, R'
\end{aligned}\tag{1}\end{equation}
where $'$ denote the transpose operator and $R$, $E$ are respectively the following rotation and extension matrices
\begin{equation*}\tag{2}R\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
c & -s \\
s & \phantom{-}c
\end{array}\right] \qquad E\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0 \\
0 & b
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
where $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$, $a,b>0$ are given parameters and
\begin{equation*}
c\triangleq \cos \theta \qquad s\triangleq \sin \theta
\end{equation*}
I'm interested in the following inversion problem: given a covariance matrix
\begin{equation*}\tag{3}
M\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
M_1 & M_{12} \\
M_{12} & M_2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
retrive the parameters $\theta,a, b$ that have generated the assigned $M$.

### Naive attempt

By combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ turns out the following non-linear system
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
M_1 &=c^2a^2+s^2b^2\\
M_2 &=s^2a^2+c^2b^2\\
M_{12} &=sc(a^2-b^2)
\end{aligned}\tag{4}
\end{equation}
which, honestly speaking, I'm not able to resolve with respect to $\theta,a,b$. The only thing that cames immediately in my mind is the following
\begin{equation*}M_1+M_2=a^2+b^2\end{equation*}
but I don't know how to use it.

### Refined attempt

Another approach that came in my mind is the following: by diagonalizing $M$ it turns out the following factorization
\begin{equation*}\tag{5}
M=D\,\Lambda\,D'
\end{equation*}
which resembles $(1)$. Here $D$ is [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), which means that, for example, can be written as
\begin{equation*}D\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
c & -s \\
s & \phantom{-}c
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
where $\theta$ is a suitable rotation angle. On the other hand, here $\Lambda$ is diagonal and contains the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of $M$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}\Lambda\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
The comparison of $(1)$ with $(5)$ gives the following relationships
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
D &= R\\
\Lambda &= EE'
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
In lieu of these two equations, holds the following:

1. $\theta$ can be extracted from $D$, for example by computing
   \begin{equation*}\theta = \textrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{D_{21}}{D_{11}}\right)=\textrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{s}{c}\right)\end{equation*}
   where $D_{11}$, $D_{21}$ are the northwest, southwest entries of $D$;
2. $a,b$ can be extracted from $\Lambda$ by computing
   \begin{equation*}a=\sqrt{\Lambda_{11}}=\sqrt{\lambda_1} \qquad b=\sqrt{\Lambda_{22}}=\sqrt{\lambda_2}\end{equation*}
   where $\Lambda_{11}$, $\Lambda_{22}$ are the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$.

Now the problem is reduced to find $s$, $c$, $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, which amounts to just diagonalize $M$.

---

**eigenvalues**

By definition, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the two roots of the characteristic polynomial of $M$, which if $I_2$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix, is given by
\begin{equation*}\chi_M(\lambda)\triangleq\text{det}(\lambda I_2-M)=\lambda^2-(M_1+M_2)\lambda+M_1M_2-M_{12}^2\end{equation*}
then, the two eigenvalues are
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{(M_1+M_2)\pm \sqrt{(M_1+M_2)^2-4(M_1M_2-M_{12}^2)}}{2}
\end{equation*}
consequently, the extension parameters $a,b$ are given by
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
a=\sqrt{\lambda_1}=\sqrt{\frac{(M_1+M_2)+\sqrt{(M_1+M_2)^2-4(M_1M_2-M_{12}^2)}}{2}}
}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{
b=\sqrt{\lambda_1}=\sqrt{\frac{(M_1+M_2)-\sqrt{(M_1+M_2)^2-4(M_1M_2-M_{12}^2)}}{2}}
}
\end{equation*}

---

**eigenvectors**

By definition, an eigenvector $v$ of $(M,\lambda)$ satisfies the equation
\begin{equation*}Mv=\lambda v\end{equation*}
and so, by writing component-wise $v=[\nu_1\,\,\nu_2]'$ it turns out the following linear system
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
(M_1-\lambda)\, \nu_1 + M_{12}\, \nu_2 &=0\\
M_{12}\, \nu_1 + (M_{2}-\lambda)\, \nu_2 &=0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
by fixing (for example) $\nu_2=1$ and by solving (for example) the first equation it turns out the following eigenvector
\begin{equation*}
v(\lambda)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda-M_1} & 1
\end{array}\right]'
\end{equation*}
whose normalization is
\begin{equation*}v_n(\lambda)\triangleq \frac{v(\lambda)}{\lVert v(\lambda)\rVert}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda-M_{1}}\right)^2+1}}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda-M_1} & 1
\end{array}\right]'\end{equation*}
In conclusion,

1. the searched eigenvectors are
   \begin{equation*}
   v_n^1 \triangleq v_n(\lambda_1)= \left[\begin{array}{c}
   \frac{M_{12}}{(\lambda_1-M_1)\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \end{array}\right] \qquad v_n^2 \triangleq v_n(\lambda_2)= \left[\begin{array}{c}
   \frac{M_{12}}{(\lambda_2-M_1)\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_2-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_2-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \end{array}\right]\\
   \end{equation*}
2. the diagonalizing matrix is
   \begin{equation*}D=\left[\begin{array}{cc} v_n^1 & v_n^2 \end{array}\right]
   = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \frac{M_{12}}{(\lambda_1-M_1)\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} &
   \frac{M_{12}}{(\lambda_2-M_1)\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_2-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} &
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_2-M_1}\right)^2+1}}
   \end{array}\right]
   \end{equation*}
3. the trigonometric parameters are
   \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
   s&=D_{21} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   c&=D_{11} = \frac{M_{12}}{(\lambda_1-M_1)\sqrt{\left(\frac{M_{12}}{\lambda_1-M_1}\right)^2+1}} \\
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation*}
4. the rotation angle is
   \begin{equation*}
   \boxed{
   \theta = \textrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{D_{21}}{D_{11}}\right)=\textrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{\lambda_1-M_1}{M_{12}}\right)
   }\end{equation*}

### Sanity checks

My solution is pretty much involved, and I don't consider it reliable at all. In order to validate my results I want to make some sanity checks.

1. If my solution is correct, plugging $(4)$ inside the final expressions of $a,b,\theta$ must give an identity. The problem is that this operations are not straightforwad.
2. The diagonalizing matrix $D$ is redundant, in the sense that there are multiple ways to compute the trigonometric parameters. Here the sanity checks are the following: is it true that $D_{11}=D_{22}$, $D_{21}=-D_{12}$? Once again, here the computations are not straightforward.

### Observation

For what concern the sanity check about the proposed solutions for $a,b$, it should be noted that, since $M_1+M_2=a^2+b^2$, if everything is ok it must be
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{(M_1+M_2)^2-4(M_1M_2-M_{12}^2)}=a^2-b^2
\end{equation*}
or, equivalently,
\begin{equation*}
M_1M_2-M_{12}^2 = a^2b^2
\end{equation*}
According to my solution, is this relation true?

### Questions

1. Is there any chance to solve $(4)$ with a simpler strategy than the one proposed by me?
2. How can I verify the sanity checks?
3. Does it make sense the idea to diagonalize $M$?